# manova () in R with between and within subject factors

Tags: r, anova, stat, manova

I am using stats() 3.5.2 to run a manova with:

- participant 1:20
- gender as between subject factor
- group as within subject factor
- anxiety as dependent measure
- BAC as dependent measures

The dataset follow:

```
treat4 = data.frame (
   participant = rep(1:20,3),
   gender = factor (rep(c(rep("male", 10), rep ("female", 10)),3)),
   group = factor (c(rep("control",20), rep("run",20), rep("party",20))),
   anxiety = round(c(rnorm(20, mean=55, sd=5),rnorm(20, mean=20, sd=5),rnorm(20, mean=75, sd=5))),
   BAC = round(c(rep(0.01,20), rep(0.01,20), rnorm(20, mean= 0.09, sd=0.01)),2))
```

I apply the manova () function and summarize  as follows:

```
mod = manova(cbind(anxiety,BAC) ~ gender + Error(group),data=treat4)
summary (mod)
```

This is what I get:

```
Error: group
          Df Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
Residuals  2                                     

Error: Within
          Df   Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
gender     1 0.013447  0.37482      2     55 0.6892
Residuals 56
```

There are a couple of issues:

1) Gender seems to be accounted as within-subjects factor

2) I don't get any statistics for the group factor

Any help?

Comment: ANOVA in general only accounts for 1 dependent measure. For more than 1, do multiple ANOVAs or MANOVA.

Comment: Thanks @M.Papenberg for your help.

Comment: Thanks. If I added gender as between-subject factor, how would I need to account for it in the manova() model? The code for the data.frame is below 
```
treat4 = data.frame (
   participant = rep(1:20,3),
   gender = factor (rep(c(rep("male", 10), rep ("female", 10)),3)),
   group = factor (c(rep("control",20), rep("run",20), rep("party",20))),
   anxiety = round(c(rnorm(20, mean=55, sd=5),rnorm(20, mean=20, sd=5),rnorm(20, mean=75, sd=5))),
   BAC = round(c(rep(0.01,20), rep(0.01,20), rnorm(20, mean= 0.09, sd=0.01)),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

if anxiety and BAC are your dependent variables, you place them on the left side of tilda (~) with cbind, to indicate multivariate response, and use `Error()` to specify the within group effect (or random effect). The rest on the right side of tilda (~) are your between group effect (or fixed effect):

```
manova(cbind(anxiety,BAC) ~ gender + Error(group),data=treat4)

Call:
manova(cbind(anxiety, BAC) ~ gender + Error(group), data = treat4)

Grand Means:
    anxiety         BAC 
49.96666667  0.03766667 

Stratum 1: group

Terms:
                 Residuals
anxiety           33156.63
BAC             0.09185333
Deg. of Freedom          2

Residual standard errors: 128.7568 0.2143051

Stratum 2: Within

Terms:
                   gender Residuals
anxiety            8.0667 1527.2333
BAC                0.0000    0.0034
Deg. of Freedom         1        56

Residual standard errors: 5.222262 0.007807201
Estimated effects are balanced
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @StupidWolf for your answer.

However, when I apply summary () to the model:

```
summary(manova(cbind(anxiety,BAC) ~ gender + Error(group),data=treat4))
```

I get the following:

```
Error: group
          Df Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
Residuals  2                                     

Error: Within
          Df   Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
gender     1 0.039097   1.1189      2     55  0.334
Residuals 56
```

There are a couple of issues:

1) Gender seems to be accounted as within-subjects factor

2) I don't get any statistics for the group factor

Comment: hey is something wrong with your installation? I ran it with your example above and it works.. and please try not to answer, i will not see it. Comment below my answer or update your question

Comment: I am using stats version 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes a bit late but I faced the same issue and I think you can simply solve it this way:

```
summary(manova(cbind(anxiety,BAC) ~ gender + group + Error(factor(participant)),data=treat4))
```

Basically, you need to add group as an IV (by doing `+ group`).
Then you use the `Error()` to indicate how it needs to identify unique subjects, it needs to do this by the participant number, rather than by the group.

Don't forget to make the participant into a factor, otherwise, it causes problems!